# PXEBoot problem, initramfs eth0 / eth1

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, debian, initramfs

I'am trying to setup my server to decrypt the main partition during preboot. It works pretty nice but sometimes (50% of the cases) when the server load it doesn't use the correct device (eth1)
[Eth1 start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twyFp.jpg)
In 50% of the other cases it boots on the correct interface eth0
[Eth0 start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx4oi.jpg)

Do you know if there is a way to force initramfs to use eth0 ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed **/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf** :

```
DEVICE=eth0
IP=163.172.xx.xx::163.172.7.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:off
```